# php while loop high cpu usage

Tags: php, loops

I have an ipcamera from which `/video/feed/1.jpg` (mounted as a ramdrive) is being written to at approx 5fps. Sometimes this can be less than 1 fps if the connection is poor.
I'm trying to update the image in a browser every 500ms but i have two goals:

- I don't want the server to output the same image if it has not been updated by the camera.
- I dont want to output a partial image if the camera had not finished writing it yet.

I tried to achieve this by creating an md5 of the image and storing it in the session, if on the next browser request the md5 is unchanged, the server loops until the md5 is different. The server will also loop until the md5 matches the previous time it was loaded, this way I can be sure that the camera had finished creating the image.

The process works as expected but the cpu usage goes through the roof, so I'm looking for suggestions on improvements.

**test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$imgFile = '/video/feed/1.jpg';
$lastImg = $_SESSION['image'];
$imgMd5 =0;
do {
    sleep(.2);
    $img = (file_get_contents($imgFile));
    $lastMd5 = $imgMd5;
    $imgMd5 = md5($img);
    if ($lastMd5 != $imgMd5) {
    continue;
    }
    if ($imgMd5 != $lastImg) {
        break;
    }
} while (0 == 0);
header("Content-type: image/jpg");
$_SESSION['image'] = md5($img);
echo $img;
exit;
?>
```

**JS**

```
      <script>
            img = new Image
            function f() {
                img.src = "test.php?rnd=" + Date.now();
                img.onload = function() {
                    feed.src = img.src;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        f();
                   }, 500);
                };
                img.onerror= function(){
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        f();
                    }, 500);
                };
            }
            f();
        </script>
```

Comment: `do ... while(0 == 0)` is loop forever!

Comment: @vee yes, but it has a delay, and will break eventually

Comment: Think about [`md5`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm) and its algorithm. It takes 64 iterations! When you do it once it's fast, but when you run it every 500 ms you could only imagine how much processing power it's eating!

Comment: @sjagr: 64 iterations is not much for a modern CPU to handle. Hashing the contents of a ~43K JPEG on my computer takes (on average) 98.8 μs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I really needed was `usleep(200000)`

`sleep(.2)` did not work as I expected.

Comment: bet your md5 method doesn't do what you first expected either. and the condition for repeating and breaking out of the loop are the same.

Comment: @symcbean They're not quite the same, `$lastMd5` is the md5 of the image on the previous loop. `$lastImg` is the md5 of the previous image (retrieved from the session) I know the naming is not too clear

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an MD5 hash to check if the file changed, use the last modified time which *should* be less resource-intensive than computing an MD5 hash each time (but for some reason on my Windows machine it still uses a lot of CPU so I'm not sure), you can try my code :

```
<?php

session_start();

$path = "/video/feed/1.jpg";

if (isset($_SESSION["lastmodified"])) { // if there's no previous timestamp, do not execute all of this and jump straight into serving the image.
    while ($_SESSION["lastmodified"] == filemtime($path)) {
            sleep(1); // sleep while timestamp is the same as before.
            clearstatcache(); // PHP caches file informations such as last modified timestamp, so we need to clear it each time or we'll run into an infinite loop.
        }
}

$_SESSION["lastmodified"] = filemtime($path); // set the new time variable.

header("Content-type: image/jpg");
echo file_get_contents($path);

?>
```

Edit: you can just let your webserver handle all of this by directly serving the RAMdisk directory, setting appropriate cache-control headers and using a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_refresh) tag to reload the page every second. When the page reloads, the webserver will serve a new image only if it exists (and if not, it'll just return "not modified" to the browser and it'll serve the last image from its cache).